# Deleting "weak homeomorphism" in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

It is well-known that there exists a homeomorphism $h$
from an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$ to $H\setminus\{0\}$.
Does there exist a "weak homeomorphism" $g:H \to H\setminus\{0\}$,
that is, $g$ is bijective, and $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are weakly continuous?